# Is it possible to fuzz the RFCOMM protocol for bluetooth on Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, rfcomm, fuzzing

I'm trying to look in to whether or not it is possible to fuzz the RFCOMM protocol for bluetooth on android.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you point me to the implementation so that I could take a look at how difficult it would be to interface it with afl-fuzz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to fuzz anything, even smoke signals, but it will often require some work. If you can't find a pre-built tool, you'll need to build it yourself.

The basic building blocks of a fuzzer are as follows:

- **Interface**: Software to talk at that protocol's level. This can be trickier for lower-level or obscure protocols.

  - In the case of Bluetooth, you might need particular hardware. Ubertooth has a reputation in the Bluetooth world.
- **Generator**: Software to generate mutations of the protocol.
- **Oracle**: One or more means of detecting when something goes wrong with the unit under test. The oracle tends to be very application-specific. Some options:

  - Response-checking: Check the protocol responses for anomalies (e.g., something different than the typical error response).
  - Debugger: If your target is Android, you might be able to detect these errors on the device. Maybe.
  - Crash: If the device stops talking period, you probably hit something.

If you're just getting started, I'd recommend downloading an open source tool like Sulley just to get yourself acquainted.

Edit: I forked Sulley to a similar tool called boofuzz, which I would now recommend, as it is a little more active and updated.